# Axios.Create alterando baseurl http para https

Tags: react, axios

Boa tarde. Tenho o seguinte código num projeto de estudo em ReactJs que estou usando Axios para requests.

```
import axios from 'axios';
    var url = 'http://site3.htempurl.com';

    const api = axios.create({
        baseURL: url,
        timeout: 1000,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    })

    export default api;
```

Acontece que quando vou testar requisicoes a uma api, ele altera a baserl para **https**, dando erro na requisição.

Imagem 1: erro mostrando que está sendo enviado https:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem 2: como a api está sendo chamada no service:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que pode ser?

Comment: Pode adicionar os erros e mostrar alguns prints?

Comment: Editei a pergunta colocando os prints.

Comment: Na aba network retorna qual status?